# How to resolve Lotus Notes Client call SUNPKCS11 error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory"

Tags: java, lotus-notes

My environment is on Domino9 and Notes Client 901
 its' jre version is java6, and I copy 2 files sunpkcs11.jar and j2pkcs11.dll from jre folder to Notes\JVM folder.

When I run the code ,it shows error in line "PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)smartCardKeyStore.getKey(alias, null);" , and error message is below

```
Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.loadPkey(P11KeyStore.java:1325)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineGetKey(P11KeyStore.java:302)
at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:196)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:43)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:281)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:672)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
```

it looks like lost sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory this class?but I don't know where to find this class file, someone knows how to resolve this issue ?

```
String pkcs11config ="name=CHTSmartCard\n" + "library=D:\\Dll\\PKCS11v32.dll";
String pin = "12345";
Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(new     ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11config.getBytes()));
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
KeyStore smartCardKeyStore;
smartCardKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
smartCardKeyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());
Enumeration aliasesEnum = smartCardKeyStore.aliases();
String alias = (String)aliasesEnum.nextElement();
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)smartCardKeyStore.getKey(alias, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy rt.jar from jre folder to Notes\JVM\lib\ext folder and this question is fixed.